# Calling two new instances and waiting for return

Tags: powershell

I am having difficulty writing a script that calls two other powershell functions (in different windows) and then waits for them to terminate before proceeding.

I started by using the below (example command) where the command will take an hour or so to complete:

```
invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-01'}'
```

But this doesnt seem to wait for the new window to terminate before continuing.

I also looked into `start-job` and `wait-job` but couldnt find a way to make it work, especially with creating two jobs in parallel and waiting for both to complete.

Does anyone have any advice?

UPDATE: Thanks to Bassie I can use the following:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-01'}"
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-02'}" -Wait
```

But while this runs both at the same time it only waits for the latter, and adding a wait option to the first command will cause them to run sequentially... Anyway to get the wait function to include both commands as an AND instead of OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Start-Process`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c timeout 5" -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c timeout 5"
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c timeout 5"
```

Here we are calling `Start-Process` on `cmd` and then running whatever command we want from that window (in this case I am just sleeping for 5 seconds with `timeout` to illustrate the `-Wait` switch).

The second line will not execute until after the 5 seconds, but the third line will not wait (it will run as soon as the second line call is complete).

So in your case you could try:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-01'}" -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c Whatever you need to do next"
```

---

**Update**

If you need both commands to run at the same time, and also wait for both to complete, you can combine this with `Start-Job`:

```
$job1 = {Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-01'}" -Wait}
$job2 = {Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c Whatever you need to do next"}

Start-Jon -ScriptBlock $job1
Start-Jon -ScriptBlock $job2

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Out-Null

Write-Host "HELLO"
```

The above will wait until both jobs are complete before write `HELLO` to the host.

Comment: This looks pretty good to start with but I need two new instances to run to completion, so I guess while I can do:
    Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-01'}"
    Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c start powershell -Command {GetSeriesDate -- '2016-01-02'}" -Wait

It isnt definite the first command will have completed before the 2nd command. Is there a way to wait for both to complete, but also run them at the same time? Perhaps storing the run status as a variable and doing a 'while'?

Comment: Awesome thats perfect - Thanks for the help, accepted as answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run them concurrently while also waiting for completion your best bet is to wrap the start-process with a -wait param in a scriptblock and then launch it as a job, then do a get-job | wait-job | receive-job to gather the data (you can also use a while loop for the waiting if you prefer)

Script would look something like below -

```
$SB1 = {
    Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c timeout 5" -Wait
}
$SB2 = {
    Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "/c timeout 5" -Wait
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $SB1
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $SB2

get-job | wait-job | receive-job
```

Comment: Cheers Mike, I think I will use a combination of yours and Bassie's (I prefer the direct powershell.exe call)